# SwifUI - Custom color looks "plain" on device and simulator (not works on Preview)

Tags: swiftui, color-picker

**UPDATE:**
Just to clarify I have set the same color for dark and light mode.

---

I made a simple CustomColorPicker with the following code:

```
struct CustomColorPicker: View {
@Binding var selectedColor: Color
let colors: [Color] = [Color("my_blue"),
                       Color("my_blue_light"),
                       Color("my_yellow"),
                       Color("my_red"),
                       Color("my_green"),
                       Color("my_pink"),
                       Color("my_orange"),
                       Color("my_purple")]
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack(spacing: 18) {
            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                Button(action: {
                    self.selectedColor = color
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: self.selectedColor == color ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                }.accentColor(color)
            }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Then, proceeded to create a super simple view like this:

```
struct CreateEmojiColor: View {

@State private var selectedColor = Color("my_blue")

var body: some View {
    CustomColorPicker(selectedColor: $selectedColor)
        .padding(.vertical)
 }
}
```

and everything works fine. This is the result:

[image]

I then embedded the "CreateEmojiColor" view inside a List like this:

```
NavigationStack {
        VStack{
            List{
                Section{
                    otherView()
                    CreateEmojiColor()
                    otherView2()
                    otherView3()
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

The problem is that when I run the code on the simulator or the device, this is the result:

[image]

Can't figure out why. Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks guys.

Comment: Looks like you have white defined for all of your colors when in dark mode. Check your assets file.

Comment: No, I have the same color definded for light and dark mode. In Light Mode the colors look dark. Just like the text.

Comment: Can you use `buttonStyle(.plain)` for the buttons?

Comment: Does it happen if you define colors in code, rather than in resources? I bet not, so it's about how you define your colors in resources, not the code you posted. Next question: does it happen for light theme? If yes, then it's a problem with loading resource itself. If not, then it's a ptoblem with dark theme definition

Comment: Check if you set foreground color in any of the parent view, in that case use `.foregroundStyle()` instead of `.accentColor()`.  I tried in your code, for some reason `accentColor` is replaced by parent views's `foregroundColor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may happen to have the same problem, Asad reply did the trick for me.

The ".accentColor" modifier was overwriting the colors.
Using ".foregroundStyle(color)" instead solved the problem.
Thanks Asad.